# Additional conditions for uniform convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces. The set of all bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ is denoted by $L(X,Y)$. $L(X,Y)$ becomes a Banach space with the operator norm.

The set of all compact linear operators from $X$ to $Y$ is denoted by $K(X,Y)$.

It is well known that $K(X,Y)$ is a closed subspace of $L(X,Y)$.

**My question**

Assume $\{T_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset K(X,Y)$ strongly converges to some $T \in L(X,Y)$. That is, for all $x \in X$, $T_{n}x \to Tx$ in $Y$.

Is there any sufficient conditions such that $T_{n}$ converges to $T$ with respect to operator norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know what you are looking for but a necessary and sufficient cndition would be that the sequence be relatively compact in the norm topology.